# Incorrect behaviour of size() and at() in string class

Tags: c++

I've got this code:

```
string test("żaba");

cout << "Word: " << test << endl;
cout << "Length: " << test.size() << endl;
cout << "Letter: " << test.at(0) << endl;
```

The output is strange:

```
Word: żaba
Length: 5
Letter: �
```

As you can see, length should be 4 and letter: "ż".

How can I correct this code to work properly?

Comment: These are Unicode characters, therefore you should probably be using the wide versions of these functions/datatypes: `std::wstring` and `std::wcout`.

Comment: Essential reading: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: have a look at this: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/multibyte

Comment: @Cody on Windows, right?

Comment: @Cody No. Read the [UTF-8 Everywhere manifesto](http://utf8everywhere.org/). They make a very strong case against wide character varieties. Apart from that, I think it’s safe to say that this code isn’t on Windows since otherwise the output would be garbage anyway.

Comment: @Mahmoud Yup, Windows. As a Windows programmer, I do make that implicit assumption. Probably why my instincts said to post that as a comment rather than an answer. :-)

Comment: I'm a WIN32 developer turned Mac/Linux dev, so I just get confused and walk into a wall. :)

Comment: @Konrad Interesting advice, but not something I'm particularly inclined to follow... *Way* too much work since almost everything I do involves making calls to Win32 APIs. Totalizing "only do x" statements need to be taken with a grain of salt.

Comment: @Cody Well the manifesto does address this fact specifically, and they do provide convenience wrappers to circumvent this somewhat. I can’t comment on the usefulness of those (I’ve left the sinking ship “Windows” some time ago, if you’ll allow me flame a bit) but the authors seem to have been using them in day to day business for quite some time.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, the manifesto seems more like an argument that `wchar_t` should be 4bytes in order to hold a proper code point. That is, UTF-8 is fine for serialization, but in memory UTF-32 does have distinct advantages (if you actually need to do string processing).

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y Does the manifesto actually touch on this? If so, you can always use a `basic_string<uint32_t>` – not that this will do you much good since using a wider character type doesn’t make C++ strings magically understand about Unicode forms.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, it's absense leaves the manifesto incomplete. Half of the argument for UTF-8 is merely that UTF-16 sucks. This still leaves UTF-32 as a totally valid and easy to use encoding (it likely also compresses just as well as the others, but still has the endian issue). You are correct though that one can just totally ignore `wchar_t` and use a `uint32_t`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: If you use `std::basic_string` with `uint32_t` then you would have to provide your own character traits class as the standard library doesn't provide a specialization of `std::char_traits` for `uint32_t` and you can't provide an explicit specialization for `std::char_traits<uint32_t>` as `uint32_t` is not a user-defined type. This means you would have to use `std::basic_string<uint32_t, MyTraits<uint32_t>>` or similar. It's a total pain.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y Well, the manifesto *does* address UTF-32, in particular to relativise the advantage of string processing (but yes, it *still* has an advantage). I would just add that for things like file names, UTF-8 is still superior to UTF-32 (due to transparent handling by Unix APIs) and that UTF-32 may just be prohibitively expensive for some applications (but really: which ones? Can’t think of any just now).

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y: The reason that UTF-8 is simpler than UTF-32 and UTF-16 to work with is that UTF-8 is byte oriented while all our communication channels and files are also byte oriented. Therefore if you wish to standardize on one encoding for everything it also must be byte oriented.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::string` on non-Windows is usually used to store UTF8 strings (being the default encoding on most sane operating systems this side of 2010), but it is a "dumb" container that in the sense that it doesn't know or care anything about the bytes you're storing. It'll work for reading, storing, and writing; but not for string manipulation.

You need to use the excellent and well-maintained [IBM ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/): International Components for Unicode. It's a C/C++ library for *nix or Windows into which a ton of research has gone to provide a culture-aware string library, including case-insensitive string comparison that's both fast and accurate.

Another good project that's easier to switch to for C++ devs is [UTF8-CPP](http://utfcpp.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: "std::string on non-Windows is UTF8" -- No, not at all!  `std::string`  does not care about character encodings, it just manages arrays of characters of type `char`.

Comment: Drop the UTF8 reference!  Although `std::string` can *hold* these strings, it will only work with single-character encodings.  Not even the `length()` is correct.  What's the point in using `std::string` to hold multi-byte encoded UTF-8 if you can do nothing with it?  You could just as well use a `std::vector<char>` then.

Comment: That's what `std:string` is, anyway: just a glorified vector of characters with a few object-oriented string manipulation functions. Why would I drop the UTF8 reference if that's what the question is about (issues storing unicode strings in `std::string`)? Regardless of whether or not it does so with elegance, `std::string` *is* used to store UTF8-encoded strings (and, yes, there are better alternatives). Updated post to include UTF8-CPP.

Comment: @FerdinandBeyer: `length()` is correct, it's just not what *you* expect it to be. See my answer [here](http://benlynn.blogspot.com/2011/02/utf-8-good-utf-16-bad_07.html?showComment=1336857237976#c4498352344220714190), and [more discussion about 'length'](http://www.utf8everywhere.org/#myths).

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi: I think I see your point now.  Unfortunately, there is no "suitable" container type to store and *handle* UTF-8 data in C++ and even apparently trivial things such as determining the length of a string are surprisingly hard to do right with Unicode.  As long as you treat strings as opaque, storing them UTF-8 encoded in a `std::string` is probably the best way to go, since most of the times, you really don't care for the contents of a string anyway.  Your counter-position helped me deepening my knowledge about Unicode and proper encoding, thank you for that!

Comment: @Ferdinand You're welcome - our discussion led me to do some more reading on string encoding in the STL as well. Cheers!

Answer (score 7):

Your question fails to mention encodings so I’m going to take a stab in the dark and say that this is the reason.

First course of action: read [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

After that, it should become clear that such a thing as a “naked string” doesn’t exist – every string is encoded somehow. In your case, it looks very much like you are using a UTF-8-encoded string with diacritics, in which case, yes, the length of the string is (correctly) reported as 5<sup>1</sup>, and the first code point might not be printable on your platform.

---

<sup>1)</sup> Note that `string::size` counts *bytes* (= `char`s), not logical characters or even code points.